# Controller Advice bean not instantiated at proper order in Spring Boot 2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm implementing an global exception handling using `ControllerAdvice` and have trouble having it working with Spring Boot 2.4.

I have a `class SecurityExceptionTranslater` that is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and `implements ExceptionTranslater` where `ExceptionTranslater` is an custom interface.

`SecurityExceptionTranslater` is an managed bean introduced in my `@Configuration` configuration

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@AutoConfigureAfter(SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@AutoConfigureBefore(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
public class SecurityAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ExceptionTranslater.class)
    public ExceptionTranslater exceptionTranslater() {
        return new SecurityExceptionTranslater();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, SecurityWebSupport support) throws Exception {
        return http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(support)
                .accessDeniedHandler(support)
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebSupport securityProblemSupport(
            @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver) {
        return new SecurityWebSupport(handlerExceptionResolver);
    }

}
```

`SecurityWebSupport` is used to take over exception handling thrown by Spring Security.

```java
public class SecurityWebSupport implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, AccessDeniedHandler {

    private final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    public SecurityWebSupport(final HandlerExceptionResolver resolver) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                         final AuthenticationException exception) {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                       final AccessDeniedException exception) {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, exception);
    }

}
```

As far as I have been inspecting into Spring Boot, `exceptionTranslater` bean is always created after creation of `handlerExceptionResolver` defined in `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, where Controller beans are collected and manipulated. For that `exceptionTranslater` has not been instantiated yet and `ExceptionTranslater` neither is annotated with `@ControllerAdive` nor contains any `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method, `exceptionTranslater` is ignored by `handlerExceptionResolver`.

However, the configuration works if

1. Spring Boot is downgraded to 2.3
2. or `SecurityWebSupport` bean is removed
3. or return type of `@Bean` method `exceptionTranslater` is modified as concrete type `SecurityExceptionTranslater`

By doing 1. and 2., `exceptionTranslater` bean is created before `handlerExceptionResolver`.

By doing 3., `exceptionTranslater` is still created after `handlerExceptionResolver` but it will be proper registered because of `@ControllerAdvice` annotation and `@ExceptionHanlder` method.

I'm looking forward to an explanation and a solution.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was closer to the answer. After another few hours digging into it, I finally find out the cause.

The root cause is `@AutoConfigureAfter(SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)`.

SecurityAutoConfiguration depends on `SecurityFilterChain` and in my configuration, my custom `SecurityAutoConfiguration` depends on `SecurityWebSupport`, which depends on `HandlerExceptionResolver`. This is why my `ExceptionTranslater` is always instantiated before `HandlerExceptionResolver`.

I ignored the annotation while I was adapting my code to work with Spring Boot 2.4.